# How to optimize scraping a dynamically loaded site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to gather all shoes on https://www.flightclub.com/ using Python. Since the site is dynamically loaded, I am using selenium web driver. The problem with this is it takes a very long time to load the page and run. Is there a way to optimize this code, so I dont have to run `time.sleep(5)` to wait for the page to load, so the code will run much faster?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#url of the page we want to scrape
url = "https://www.flightclub.com/adidas/adidas-yeezy"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'.\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
result = []
for i in range(1, 15):
    temp = []
    # initiating the webdriver. Parameter includes the path of the webdriver.
    driver.get(url+ "?page="+str(i))

    # this is just to ensure that the page is loaded
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    temp = soup.find_all('a', class_='sc-12adlsx-0 iSXeRZ')
    result.extend(temp)
    print("Result len: "+ str(len(result)))

shoes = []
for res in result:
    try:
        print("------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Title: "+res.find('img', class_='sc-htpNat ipJcZu')['alt'])
        print("Price: "+str(res.find('div', class_='yszfz8-5 kbsRqK').text.split()[0]) +  " USD")
        print("Picture: "+res.find('img', class_='sc-htpNat ipJcZu')['src'])
        print("Link: "+"https://www.flightclub.com" + res.get('href'))
    except:
        print("Shoe not found")
print(f"\nFound total shoes: {len(result)}")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Selenium already has a dynamic HTML parser. I don't see the point in using bs4. Just use Selenium to do selection.

Answer (score 0):

repliying to your question, removing time.sleep will make the processing of your code faster, but you should see if the website is being responsive enough(that means the speed depends on how fast the website will respond/load), and keep in mind poor internet connection might also affect the speed of your code when is comes to scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Waits a maximum of 10 seconds, or until that element is found on the page
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```